# Showing friend my jsp project

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I am using eclipse with tomcat to develop my jsp projects. Is it possible for me to be able to show this to my friend remotely? Without them having tomcat or anything. Without purchasing a web hosting service?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
 Login to your router and configure a rule for port 8080 (tomcat port).
Go [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)  to find out your external IP. Your friend should be able to access your tomcat context by using your external IP on port 8080.
Also - make sure your firewall/Anti Virus in allowing this connection.
Hope that helps!
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer would be my choice, they can remote into your machine and it will be like they are sitting there with you. If things go nasty, just turn off your network.